# Javascript error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a chat for my site. It works fine, but a function isn't working inside of a HTML button. I have 3 files I use for it, and one line isn't working.

Before, I had an issue where I set the Javascript function, create the button, and it would say the function doesn't exist. I fixed that, by putting the function below the buttons.

Each button shows an online member, who is on your friends list.

The error I get in confusing me, as I have no idea how this is being caused.

> Error: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } users.php:3'

(users.php is the page I was on, if I change it that changes to the page name.)

With chrome, I can click on the error, that brings up this: 'window.script1357688207590=1;'

Scripts (sorry for being so long):

Script 1: (main script):

```
    var username = '[error]';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'bchat.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { method: 'method2' },
            success: function(data){
                username = data;
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: 'bchat.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { method: 'method1' },
            success: function(data){
                if(data!='do not show chat'){
                    function ToggleChat(tof){
                        if(tof == true){
                            $('#chatWindow').css('visibility','visible');
                        }else{
                            $('#chatWindow').css('visibility','hidden');
                        }
                    }
                    $('body').append('\
                        <div id=chatWindow style="background:white; visibility

:hidden; position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; margin-top:-30px; width:200px; height:350px;">\
                        <div style="width:100%; height:100%; border:solid black 1px;">\
                            <div style="hieght:20px; background:rgb(40,40,40); color:white;">\
                                '+data+'<span>  </span>'+username+'\
                                <button id=chat_close style="float:right; background:rgba(0,0,0,0); border:none; color:white;">\
                                    Close\
                                </button>\
                            </div>\
                            <div id=chatOnline style="overflow:auto;">\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div id=chat__window style="background:white; visibility:hidden; position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 200; margin-top:-30px; margin-left:-400px; width:200px; height:350px;">\
                        \
                    </div>\
                    <div id=chat style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0;">\
                        <button id=chat_open style="border:none; padding:5px; color:whiteSmoke; background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #4A4A4A 0%, #00070A 100%);background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #4A4A4A 0%, #00070A 100%);background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #4A4A4A 0%, #00070A 100%);background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #4A4A4A), color-stop(1, #00070A));background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #4A4A4A 0%, #00070A 100%);background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #4A4A4A 0%, #00070A 100%); width:200px; height:30px;">\
                            '+data+' <span>  </span>Chat\
                        </button>\
                    </div>');
                $('#chat_open').click(function() {
                     ToggleChat(true);
                });
                $('#chat_close').click(function() {
                     ToggleChat(false);
                });
            }   
        }   
    });
    //
    //update online users
    //
    function updateOnline(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'bchat.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { method: 'method3' },
            success: function(data){
                $('#chatOnline').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    updateOnline();
    setInterval(updateOnline,5000);
```

Script 2 (function script):

```
function chatWith(url,un){
                                $('#chat__window').html('<div style="width:100%; height:100%; margin-top:-30px; border:solid black 1px;"><div style="hieght:20px; background:rgb(40,40,40); color:white;">'+url+'<span>  </span>'+un+'<button id=chat_chatting_close style="float:right; background:rgba(0,0,0,0); border:none; color:white;">Close</button></div><div id=chat_chats style="overflow:auto;"></div></div>');
                                $('#chat__window').css('visibility','visible');
}
```

PHP script (bchat.php):

```
<?php
    include_once("./login_manager_php_file.php");
    if($username&&$userid){
        $method = $_POST['method'];
        if($method){
            if($method=='method1'){
                $url = $images['logged_in'];
                $html = "<img src='".$url."' width=7.5 height=7.5/>";
            }elseif($method=='method2'){
                echo $username;
            }elseif($method=='method3'){
                $friends_q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE `with`='$username' OR `friender`='$username'");
                $thtml = '';
                if($friends_q){
                    while($friend = mysql_fetch_assoc($friends_q)){
                        if($friend['with']==$username){
                            $usern = $friend['friender'];
                        }else{
                            $usern = $friend['with'];
                        }
                        $url = '';
                        if(ifLoggedIn($usern)===true){
                            $url = $images['logged_in'];
                        }else{
                            $url = $images['logged_out'];
                        }
                        if(ifLoggedIn($usern)===true && $usern != $username){
                            $on = $url;
                            $html = "

                            <button onClick='
                                chatWith('$url','$usern');
                            '
                            style='border:none; background:rgba(0,0,0,0);'><img src='".$url."' width=7.5 height=7.5/>";
                            $thtml = $thtml.$html.$usern.'</button><br/>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                echo $thtml;
            }elseif($method==='method4'){
                if($_POST['usrn']){
                    $url = '';
                    if(ifLoggedIn($_POST['usrn'])===true){
                        $url = $images['logged_in'];
                    }else{
                        $url = $images['logged_out'];
                    }
                    echo "<img src='".$url."' width=7.5 height=7.5/>";
                }else{
                    echo '[error]';
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo 'do not show chat';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Everything works, but the function on the button for the online users, where onClick='chatWith();'

Comment: You may want to review your PHP code, to ensure you are not at risk of SQL injection in the select statement, since you are not sanitizing or checking the input from the client. What would happen for a user name of "O'Rielly" (or worse!)?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the php to add an id attribute to the button, or class if there is going to be more than one. Also, remove the onclick attribute

```
<button class="btnChat" ...
```

Just realized you will need to add in the parameters as well.  I would add those to data attributes on the button.

```
<button class="btnChat" data-url="$url" data-usern="$usern"
```

You will need to make sure the $url and $usern are escaped properly

then in the script 2 file you can hook up the click event for that button:

```
$(function(){

  $('body').on('click','.btnChat',function(){
      chatWith($(this).data('url'),$(this).data('usern'));
  });

});
```

Comment: Well, I can't do that. There is info that the PHP gets for the javascript function. Then again, I could use ajax to get the information inside of that function. I will try that.

Comment: I do my click function differently. Could I do $('.btnChat').click(chatWith(something,something)); ?

Comment: It is (sorta) working, I don't get the error, but it doesn't submit it to the chatWith function correctly. I double checked and logged abc into the console, in the function, clicked it, and it doesn't log it.

Comment: Of course, i forgot that the button isn't on the page when the event is hooked up.. i just made a change to the answer, this way the event will fire.

Comment: Thank you, it is now working, the .click(function(){ }); doesn't work? Cause that is what it was before.

Comment: yup, the click function depends on the button being present when the event is hooked up, whereas this approach does not.  The event is actually attached to the body in this case, so it has to bubble up the dom to find out what to do